# How do I show a detailed program in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In a tabulator document (http://tabulator.info/examples/4.3?#responsive-layout-collapse), they already support collapse mode, but it is automatically done by Tabulator. However, my wish is difference. I have 20 columns, I want to show 5 columns only, and the others will expand when I select a row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see using a row callback: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/callbacks#row say rowClick and then use: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/columns#visibility col.show()/col.hide() to display/hide the columns. You might have to do table.redraw() to get the table to catch up with customize the changes in formatting. The best way is use responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter(http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/layout#responsive)

Comment: actually I prefer a button to "Show more" content.when click on that, it will show rest of content in a custom format, like what DataTable did

Comment: Have you looked at (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/layout#responsive):  

"Collapsed List Show/Hide

If you would like your users to be able to interact with the list and hide/show it as needed you can add a column that uses the built-in responsiveCollapse formatter that provides a control for toggling the visibility of the collapsed list"


Otherwise you will have to build your own mechanism.  You might be able to 'borrow' some ideas from the code in responsive_layout.js.

Comment: Actually you can use `responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter` at above link to customize the formatting.

Comment: `responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter` is what I need. For any one need an example, you can take a look here, https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1708.
@Adrian can you update/edit your answer above, then I will mark it as accepted answer